# Office 365 API ADFS

Tags: c#, rest, office365, office365-apps

I'm trying display an unread message count of an Exchange Online mailbox in a C# WPF application.  We have ADFS (2008 R2) SSO implemented on-premises and use DirSync to Office365. We always receive an authentication prompt when doing the request with the REST API, however SSO works (via ADFS) when accessing Outlook Web App.

I'm trying to access via [this](https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=IsRead%20eq%20false)

There is little documentation of using the REST API with ADFS deployed, and I'd like to know if the REST API is compatible with ADFS (2008 R2) SSO at all? The documentation over on the REST API pages, has no mention at all of ADFS, despite it being a common authentication mechanism for Enterprise Office365 customers.

Answer (score 0):

Our Rest APIs do not support federated access, so even when you integrate your app with federation, the API access will not work. You can however use OAuth2 to get an access token for the Rest APIs. In the OAuth2 flow you can however take advantage of federation, as OAuth2 will hit the authorize endpoint for consent, and the authorize endpoint will honor an existing sign-on session your app has with AAD (via ADFS). So the user of your app does most likely not see the credential prompt, and your app get access tokens from the AAD Oauth2 token issuing endpoint following the Oauth2 protocol: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645542.aspx. Note as your app is developed in C# .net, you can fully take advantage of the OAuth2 auth library, ADAL, and you do not need to implement the protocol by yourself. We have many examples available and a good starting point is: http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/05/06/azure-ad-samples-on-github/.

Hope this helps.

Thanks,
Matthias

Comment: As I understand it, OAuth2 requires ADFS 3.0 (2012 R2), and currently we  run ADFS 2 (2008 R2).
We can't upgrade in the short-term, is there an alternative authentication solution perhaps?

Comment: Not quite. Exchange Online APIs are hooked up with AAD as authority, meaning an application must be registered with AAD and get access tokens from AAD to address Office 365 Rest APIs. Now, if your user credentials live on-premises (your users sign-on with on-premises credentials), you can deploy ADFS for means of SSO into the authorization endpoint of AAD. This has very little do do with the actual OAuth2 access token to access the Rest APIs. Basically your client app hits the authorize endpoint of AAD, AAD prompts for user creds for the authorize endpoint, ....

Comment: ...AAD will redirect to ADFS sign-on in case the user enters a username with a domain that is federated, the user sees the ADFS sign-on page and enters the on-premises creds, ADFS authenticates the user with AD and does the federation magic with AAD  so the AAD authorize endpoint authenticates the user (by means of federation). Then the user sees the AAD consent, the app gets to code and hits the AAD token issuing endpoint to redeem the code for a refresh/access token pair....

Comment: ...From there it's business as usual. So it all depends what AAD supports as federation server regards ADFS to make this work, independent of the OAuth2 protocol in this scenario, as all that needs to happen is that the AAD authorize endpoint can successful authenticate the user via federation.

Comment: This is beginning to make sense :)
However we can't add applications to our AAD at the moment. When accessing AAD from our portal, we just get a sign-up page. Our DirSync from on-premises AD doesn't require any visibility of AAD. It's been running like this for circa 2 years.

Comment: AAD is now set up for our tenant and we're beginning to set this up. Our ADFS does a check for a specific user-agent string and redirects  to /adfs/ls/auth/integrated/?<url> if the string is found (i.e. if a user is signed into an AD joined computer). Thus, they don't need to enter a username and password at all. Should this work if I pass the user-agent string as part of the original hit on the authorize endpoint of AAD. Will this endpoint pass the user-agent string through when it redirects to ADFS?
Furthermore, can we avoid the AAD consent, and pre-authorise the API to have consent to O365?